# Get instagram user stories

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

In my app, user atuhenticates with instagram, and we get an access token!

This is good, and we can access all regular posts. But it seems so unclear how to access the user's stories.

this works for posts:

```
 'https://graph.instagram.com/$userID/media?fields=id,caption&access_token=$accessToken'
```

Ive tried this for stories:

```
 'https://graph.instagram.com/$userID/stories?fields=id,caption&access_token=$accessToken'

 'https://graph.instagram.com/$userID/stories&access_token=$accessToken'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API in order to list User Stories as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories).

```
GET graph.facebook.com
    /17841405822304914/stories
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).